# How to disassemble the PS4 fan and drop oil in it?

Tags: ps4

I need to open the PS4 fan and apply a drop of sewing machine oil because it is somewhat stuck.

But there is no screw on it like a computer fan.

[image: Fan bottom side]
[image: Fan top side]

Comment: What do you mean by "somewhat stuck"?

Comment: It is not stuck, but is slow and not fluent.